# Hamburger menu button changes to x button

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a hamburger button which turns to x when clicked. Everything is working fine, I just can't make the x sign in a perfect shape. I wanna know how many pixels should I translate the top and bottom bars of the hamburger menus. This is my code:

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  y = document.querySelector(".header__hamburger");
  y.classList.toggle("click");
}
```

```css
.bar {
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 36px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.header__hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 3em;
}

.click .hamburger__bar1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 12px);
}

.click .hamburger__bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.click .hamburger__bar3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -12px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header__hamburger" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <div class="bar hamburger__bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar hamburger__bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar hamburger__bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're up against a deadline, you could repurpose one of these: https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop. There'd be no need to fiddle with the pixels.

Comment: Looks like a decent symmetrical X to me

Comment: @Stucco: I'm not in rush but thanks for this resource, that could be helpful too.

Comment: @Merigold: I did using trial and error, I wanna know how to calculate the numbers.

Comment: @AndrewFakhry looks like you translate the y position 1/3 of the bar's width. The sign of the translated pixels depends whether you rotated it below or above the origin of the coordinate plane. So if you rotated `bar3` -45 degrees to the y axis, you give a y translate of `let value = 0 -
 (bar3.getBoundingClientRect().width/3)`. So, `translate(0, value)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
      function toggleMenu() {
        y = document.querySelector(".header__hamburger");
        y.classList.toggle("click");
      }
```

```css
.bar {
position: absolute;
width: 36px;
height: 3px;
background-color: #000;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.hamburger__bar1{
      top: -8px;
}
 .hamburger__bar3{
      top: 8px;
 }
  .header__hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 3em;
  }
  .header__hamburger > div{
      position: relative;
  }
  .click .hamburger__bar1 {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        top: 0;  
  }
  .click .hamburger__bar2{
        opacity: 0;
       
  }
  .click .hamburger__bar3{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        top: 0;  
  }
```

```html
<div class="header__hamburger" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <div>
     <div class="bar hamburger__bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar hamburger__bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar hamburger__bar3"></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure and simple. Accessible from the keyboard.

```html
<button type="button" class="burger" title="Open" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

```css
/* Burger button */

.burger {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px; height: 22px;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger:before,
.burger:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.burger:before { top: 0; }

.burger:after { bottom: 0; }

.burger span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 9px;
  width: 100%; height: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

/* Burger button - active */

.burger.active:before {
  top: 9px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.burger.active:after {
  bottom: 9px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.burger.active span { transform: scale(0); }
```

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');

function toggleMenu() {
  if (!burger.classList.contains('active')) {
    burger.classList.add('active');
    burger.setAttribute('title', 'Close');
  } else {
    burger.classList.remove('active');
    burger.setAttribute('title', 'Open');
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).